# Partial Least Squares Regression using only base R (no packages)

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a large dataset with one dependent variable and hundreds of explanatory MIR spectra variables.
I want to use a training set and test set to predict the dependent variable using Partial Least squares regression in Base R, I don't want to use any packages.

I.e I want to replicate the function plsr() in the pls package but using only base r with no packages.
I'm been attempting this for quite some time now and I just don't seem to be making any headway. If anyone has done something like I've described here, I'd love to know how you pulled it off!
Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Please read the information about asking questions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and, in particular, provide a reproducible example of the code (including all library statements and inputs) that anyone else can copy and paste into their session to run which shows the plsr code you are trying to reproduce without packages.  Use `dput` to show the inputs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.